# SDL_GetWindowSurface with SDL_CreateRenderer

Tags: c++, sdl

Im programming a game with SDL2 in C++.

I want to use SDL_GetWindowSurface and SDL_CreateRenderer in this game, if I use only one of them, its works, but if I try to use both of them, the game crashes.

I think that this two functions don´t work if both are active.

Can this be the problem?

Comment: The example for getwindowsurface says "instead of creating a renderer draw to surface directly" - so maybe you can't do both (I don't know for sure) https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface

Comment: Do you know what is better of those?

Comment: I do not, sorry.   I'm guessing iti would depend on exactly what you're trying to do (maybe the renderer is higher level?  not sure).   I really don't have any info other than what I saw in a quick glance at their wiki I linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think that this two functions don´t work if both are active.
>
> Can this be the problem?

Yup, exactly as [the `SDL_GetWindowSurface()` declaration comment](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/7846ac86d46e/include/SDL_video.h#l833) indicates:

```
/**
 *  \brief Get the SDL surface associated with the window.
 *
 *  \return The window's framebuffer surface, or NULL on error.
 *
 *  A new surface will be created with the optimal format for the window,
 *  if necessary. This surface will be freed when the window is destroyed.
 *
 *  \note You may not combine this with 3D or the rendering API on this window.
 *
 *  \sa SDL_UpdateWindowSurface()
 *  \sa SDL_UpdateWindowSurfaceRects()
 */
extern DECLSPEC SDL_Surface * SDLCALL SDL_GetWindowSurface(SDL_Window * window);
```

Quoting for emphasis:

> You may **not** combine this with 3D or the rendering API on this window.

Answer (score 0):

```
surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
renderer = SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer(surface);
if (!renderer) {
    SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Render creation for surface fail : %s\n",SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.